# Pivot Table Filter Button

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot-table

I am working on VBA code in Excel to filter a pivot table (on a different sheet with a different data source) based on the selection on a different pivot table using a button.

I have gone on multiple forums and altered code to my needs but I have been unsuccessful in connecting the code to my needs. I have tried code such as objects and modules for changing pivot table filters and refreshing. I am currently working on building my code from scratch but I have hit a road block. Anything helps! Thanks

```
Option Explicit


Sub Button1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim pvtTable As PivotTable, pvtTable2 As PivotTable
Dim pvtField As PivotField, pvtField2 As PivotField
Dim pvtItem As PivotItem, pvtItem2 As PivotItem
Dim s$, a$

'ws.pvtTable.PvtField
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set pvtTable = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set pvtField = pvtTable.PivotFields("Style")

'ws2.pvtTable2.pvtField2
Set ws2 = Sheets(2)
Set pvtTable2 = ws2.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
Set pvtField2 = pvtTable2.PivotFields("Style")

'Setting the filters - issues here?
'Let s = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").pvtField
Let s = pvtField
'Let a = ws2.PivotTables("PivotTable2").pvtField2
Let a = pvtField2
Let a = s

End Sub
```

I expect to be able to select "Style" in one pivot table and then have that selection populate the other pivot table once I click on the button.

****I have edited the code to what is most recent. I do not have any errors but it is not filtering on the second sheet like I want it to. How does one filter multiple pivot tables on different sheets with different data sources?****

Comment: Quick question, have you tried using connected slicers between the pivots ?

Comment: Yes I have. Since they are on different sheets and they use different data sources they cannot be connected through slicers. I was reading that powerpivot could help but the file is already quite large and for my purposes using a powerpivot and increasing the size of the file exponentially would cause more harm than good.

Comment: You need to amend to `Let a = pvtField2`

Comment: I made the change (I also set 'Set pvtField2 = pvtTable2.PivotFields("Style")' instead of 'Set pvtField2 = pvtTable.PivotFields("Style")') but nothing happened

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas that would help me make some progress?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the greatest with pivot tables, but to help with your own future projects - you should put variables that are similar together

Also I'm not sure why you are using `Dim Target as Sheet2` when you could just `Set ws2 = Sheets(2)`

So please have a look at this and see if it still runs?

```
Option Explicit


Sub Button1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim pvtTable As PivotTable, pvtTable2 As PivotTable
Dim pvtField As PivotField, pvtField2 As PivotField
Dim pvtItem As PivotItem, pvtItem2 As PivotItem
Dim s$, a$

'ws.pvtTable.PvtField
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set pvtTable = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set pvtField = pvtTable.PivotFields("Style")

'ws2.pvtTable2.pvtField2
Set ws2 = Sheets(2)
Set pvtTable2 = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
Set pvtField2 = pvtTable.PivotFields("Style")

'Setting the filters - issues here?
Let s = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").pvtField
Let a = ws2.PivotTables("PivotTable2").pvtItem2
Let a = s

End Sub
```

Comment: When I run that code I get a 1004 run time error (method "PivotTables" of object '_Worksheet' failed. I changed Set 'pvtTable2 = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable2")' to Set 'pvtTable2 = ws2.PivotTables("PivotTable2")' and now I am getting a 438 run time error(object doesnt support this property or method). the code that is causing the error is 'Let s = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").pvtField'.

Comment: Try `Let s = pvtField`

Comment: I tried that code (I also set 'a' to pvtField) and when I change s and a to that it does not cause an error but it does not change the filter on the other sheet. Nothing happens.

Comment: That's fine. If it's not throwing an error, use that code (with my formatting above) and edit your question. That means people can help with that issue, rather than the `exception`